# Why valgrind report my memory as definitely lost 12 or 24 bytes using GLUT and PORTAUDIO

Tags: c++, opengl, valgrind, freeglut, portaudio

I wrote some code with `portaudio` and tested it with Valgrind. As a result, I got "0 bytes definitely lost". But, when I mixed it with the `glut` (freeglut) library to include graphics, I got "24 bytes definitely lost".

In the code below I simply added `glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL" )` and then I got the memory leak in Valgrind's report. I'm using glew, freeglut, portaudio, sndfile libraries. Does any know what is happening here?

```
#include "util.h"
#include "sound.h"
#include <unistd.h>

/*Funcion main para creacion de hilos de reproduccion*/
int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    sound::loadStream("../pacman.wav");// this function do Pa_Initiliaze()/Pa_OpenDefaultStream()/ 
                                       //Pa_StartStream()/
    sound::loadStream("../ya_te.wav");
     glutInit( &argc, args );
    //Create OpenGL 2.1 context
    glutInitContextVersion( 2, 1 );
    //Create Double Buffered and RGBA Window
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize( 1920, 1080 ); //size of window
    glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL" ); // leak memory start at this line
    sound::changeState(0,PLAY);  //this fucntion change pacman.wav state to PLAY in portaudio 
                                 //callback
    sound::changeState(1,PLAY); // this function change ya_te.wav state to PLAY in portaudio 
                                //callback
    sleep(1); // sleep for 1 second
    sound::soundTerminate(); // this function do Pa_closeStream , Pa_terminate();
    glutDestroyWindow(glutGetWindow());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't 'keeping track' of the window created in your call to `glutCreateWindow`, which means that (as Valgrind sees it) you can never properly free the memory used by that window.

You should store the return value of the call, like this:

```cpp
int winID = glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL" );
```

and then use the saved window identifier in your subsequent call to destroy it:

```cpp
glutDestroyWindow(winID);
```

NOTE: Even though your use of `glutGetWindow()` will (most likely) return the same value, Valgrind does not (or cannot) know this.

Comment: While this is a good informative answer, but I still keep getting valgrind complaining about lost memory.